# want to access foreign key values(in child table) whose respective primary key values(group by foreign key) must satisfied one condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have a child table task_details havin primary key tid,n one colum status n a foreign key pid(project table primay key)

i want to access only those pid whose all tasks(tid) must b completed(status='Completed')if any of the task of any project is incomplete ie(status='Running')it wont return that pid]
NOTE
each prr

Comment: Can you post your table structures?

Comment: is that working for you ? if not than can you please provide me the further details of your table structure.....

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if you got the info you want...........

Answer (score 1):

its simple select query with the where condition

```
select * from table where status='Completed'
```

or

if the status filed is part of other project table than

```
   select t.tid,t.pid FROM TASK_DETAILS as t inner join
   Project_details as p  on  t.pid = p.pid
   where p.Status = 'Completed'
```